# A statement which is not clear to me on NVIC configurations

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, interrupts, gpio-external-interrupt

See the document [here.](https://www.st.com/resource/en/programming_manual/dm00046982-stm32-cortex-m4-mcus-and-mpus-programming-manual-stmicroelectronics.pdf)

I am interested on using external interrupts, and trying to configure NVIC at register level. The statement below, which can be found in page 215, confused me:

> Each priority field holds a priority value, 0-255. The lower the
> value, the greater the priority of the corresponding interrupt. **The
> processor implements only bits[7:4] of each field, bits[3:0] read as
> zero and ignore writes.**

Especially the bold part.

If that explanation was not present, I would directly think that I can write any number (0-255) to those 8 bit fields to set the priority. But now, I am confused such that whether I can use bits [3:0] or not.

[image]

Comment: the written values in range of 0 to 255 are 'mapped' to 16 priority vales by ignoring 4 lower bits.

Comment: @Juraj how about writing 128 and 129 ? They both translate(mapped) to 8?

Comment: not to 8. to 128.

Comment: @Juraj ok, considering left most 4 bits, they both will be 8. Then they have the same priority although I intended to make them different (128 and 129)

Comment: you can't. the datasheet says they are the same priority.

Answer (score 0):

Since the MCU implements 4 bits out of 8, you have 16 priorities and they are stored in high 4 bits of the 8 bit value. So you may not use the 4 lowest bits (unless you always keep them zero that is).

Comment: I've been thinking about this for a while, so far, I understood that I can only have 16 different levels of priority between all interrupts. I accepted this. But, is there a specific reason why it is not implemented in the lower 4 bits instead of higher 4 bits which would make a lot more sense(in my opinion, at least) ?